# Power set of an identity is equal to the identity of power set?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am currently reading through a book on mathematical analysis and I don't understand why this is "given" without a proof, as I don't see the intuitive nature of it.

Define $M$ as a set, $P(M)$ as the power set of $M$, $id_M: M\to M$ the identity function of $M$, given by $\text{id}_M(x)=x$ for all $x \in M$.

Given any function $f:X\to Y$, define
$$P(f) : P(X)\to P(Y), \ \ \ A\mapsto P(f)(A)$$ 
as $P(f)(A)=f(A)$ for all proper subset $A$ of $X$.

> My question: Why is $P(\text{id}_X)=\text{id}_{P(X)}$?

I guess that $\text{id}_{P(x)} = x$ for all $x \in P(X)$? And that $P(\text{id} x) = \{A | A \subset \text{id}x\}$, $\text{id}P(x) = \{a |A \subset X\}$ (not sure about this one)?

Now I kind of need to figure out how to show that $\text{id}x = X$ maybe and then it magically explains it all?

Comment: Well, what function is $P(id_X)$?  If I take a subset of $X$, call it $A$, then according to you, $P(id_X)(A)=id_X(A)$ so...

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please consider using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in the future, it makes questions easier to read :)

Comment: Hi lulu, thanks for your quick reply. Yes, I (kind of) had it until there, because in general it was just "fill in the blanks"/recipe math, but it feels like I'm missing out on 1-2 last steps to retrace this definition (The chapter before with supremum/infimum and the proofs for bounds were way easier for me). Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show that $P(\operatorname{id}_ M)=\operatorname{id} _{P(M)}$. To show that two functions are equal, it is enough to show that their domain is equal and Elements of the domain are mapped to the same image.

Clearly $\operatorname{dom}\operatorname{id} _{P(M)} = P(M)$ by definition of $\operatorname{id}_{P(M)}$. And by definition of $P(f)$ we have $\operatorname{dom}P(\operatorname{id}_M)=P(M)$ as well.

Now we just need to show that for $A\in P(M)$ holds $P(\operatorname{id}_M)(A)=(\operatorname{id} _{P(M)})(A)$. $(\operatorname{id}_{P(M)})(A)=A$ is clear from definition of $\operatorname{id}_{P(M)}$ again. Now:

$$P(\operatorname{id}_ M)(A)=(\operatorname{id}_ M)(A)=\{(\operatorname{id}_ M)(a):a\in A\}=\{a:a\in A\}=A$$

First we use the definition of $P(f)$, then the definition of $f(A)$, then the definition of $\operatorname{id}_M$ and the last one is evident. The author thinks it's trivial because you only need to use one definition after another and don't really have to put too much thought into it. Any questions left?

Comment: Wow, that was extremely clear. Thanks a bunch. I definitely get it now. I'm actually puzzled right now on how you were able to make it look so simple for me.

Comment: @user1994928 I'm used to tutor students who have sometimes problems with the most obvious proofs, even when they fair well with more complicated ones. Also I like doing math with Mizar and that trains the eye for the small things. I'm glad my answer helped, please consider accepting it (checkmark to the left of my question). And again, welcome to StackExchange. Please have a look at MathJax and make sure to take the tour. I hope you stick around ;)